# How can I reset my new iPad Air?

Tags: ipad

My neighbor just got a new iPad Air.  Her son ran away with it and setup a passcode that he promptly forgot.  Is there a way to reset it?  They don't care about the data since they've owned it for literally 30 minutes.

It's the type that uses USB-C (which I didn't even know existed) if that helps.  We've tried to connect it to her computer, and even my computer, and the machines won't see it.

Comment: Take it back to Apple with the receipt to Apple and they may be able to reset.

Comment: That's what I told her.  I was hoping to just blank it and start over tonight, but they'll be fine going tomorrow.  Thank you for the advice.  You know how it is with a new fun toy -- they want to use it immediately.  :)

Comment: You can just enter DFU mode and factory reset, see: [Apple's guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211078)